# How to create cases for multiple purposes and just showing the count of unique IDs for multiple cases

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I wrote a CTE which helps determine a flag based off a certain client's ID and what kind of client they are. I am looking to test the counts of the Flags, and the counts are totaling out amazingly! However, I am looking to add additional columns to the very last section of my code to show the amount of IDs who have belonged in all 3 cases, or both PPP and R, PPP and RR, RR and PPP, or RR and R. Is there a way I could do this? I know SUM won't work. I'm thinking using CASE or an IF, however I am a novice to SQL and am unsure what to do.

```
   WITH ids AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(r.entry_id) AS ID
        FROM id_user AS r
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(identifiervalue) AS ID
        FROM account AS a
    )
    
,PPP as (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            LOWER(accountid) as "ID"
        FROM ppp
        WHERE (date >= '2022-11-21')
    )
    
,R as (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            LOWER(account_id) as "ID"
        FROM user
    )
    , RR as (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            LOWER(id) AS "ID"
            FROM program_member
    )
    
, Joint as (
    SELECT
    r.ID
    ,CASE WHEN p.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS "PPP Flag"
    ,CASE WHEN r.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS "R Flag"
    ,CASE WHEN rr.raid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS "RR Flag"
    FROM ids i
    LEFT JOIN PPP ppp ON i.RAID = ppp.RAID
    LEFT JOIN R r ON i.RAID = r.RAID
    LEFT JOIN RR rr on i.RAID = rr.RAID
    
----TESTING COUNTS
    SELECT
    COUNT(ID) AS "ID Count"
    ,sum("PPP Flag") AS "PPP Users"
    ,sum("R") AS "R Accounts"
    ,sum("RR Flag") AS "RR Users"
    FROM Joint
```

Comment: can you EDIT your post.  Dont look for specific "PPP", "R" or "RR Flag" strings, but what is the COLUMN that holds those respective values.  Then display a list of say 5-8 entries and what you are EXPECTING as a result, regardless of your attempted query.  We need to see what you have and what you NEED.  You have already shown what you attempted.

Comment: Apologies. Just edited @DRapp

Comment: UNION removes duplicates, so no need to do SELECT DISTINCT there.

Answer (score 0):

if all you are trying to do is get distinct counts, and how many are within each of those given flag categories, dont try to repeat then join.  They are either in the PPP, User or Program_Member table. Just get that

```
select
        UnionCnt.IDAndRaidCnt,
        P.PPPCnt,
        R.RCnt,
        RR.RRCnt        
    from
        -- this outer query returns only 1 record
        ( select 
                count(*) IDAndRaidCnt
            from
                -- this inner query returns all distinct based on the UNION result
                (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        LOWER(r.entry_id) ID
                    FROM 
                        id_user r
                    UNION
                    SELECT DISTINCT 
                            LOWER(identifiervalue) ID
                        FROM 
                            account a)
        ) UnionCnt
        JOIN
            (SELECT 
                    count( DISTINCT LOWER(accountid)) PPPCnt
                FROM 
                    ppp
                WHERE 
                    date >= '2022-11-21' ) P
            -- above will only return a single record anyhow
            on 1=1
        JOIN
            (SELECT 
                    count( DISTINCT LOWER(account_id) RCnt
                FROM 
                    user ) R
            -- also returns single row with total qualifying distinct ID count
            on 1=1
        JOIN
            (SELECT 
                    count( DISTINCT LOWER(id)) RRCnt
                FROM 
                    program_member ) RR
            -- same here, single record
            on 1=1
```